# Combo box size problem in Rich Faces

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I was working on combo box in rich faces 4.0. While doing so my requirement was to reduce the size of the combo box. I tried width and size style to reduce the size but it was not work.

Can someone please help me in reducing size of Combo Box in Rich Faces

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the width of the element, have you tried the **listWidth** and **width** attributes of the rich:comboBox tab? You can find info about these properties [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_comboBox.html) and/or [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?tab=info&cid=412208)

Though these are not for version 4 but I don't think it has changed much.